# Knockout.js mapping plugin, accessing json nested multiple levels

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Is it possible for the Knockout.js Mapping plugin to access json nested data or can it only find the first level data?

If the mapping plugin cannot access nested data is there another solution?

In my example, "Number" is mapping correctly but "DueDate" will not map.

```
// json with nested data
{
   "Level1":[
      {
         "Level2":{
            "DueDate":"\/Date(1362124800000)\/",
            },
         "Number":5499
      },
}

// Here's my data model - I need to map the "DueDate" observable.
var viewModel;
$.getJSON('/myJsonData', function (data) {
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used home grown one way recursive mapping function. It has worked well for me and it's tiny.

```
function convertToObservable(obj) {
    var newObj = {},
        key,
        value;

    if (!$.isPlainObject(obj)) {
        return obj;
    }

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            value = obj[key];
            // console.log(key + ':', value);
            newObj[key] = $.isArray(value)
                ? ko.observableArray($.map(value, convertToObservable))
                : $.isPlainObject(value) ? convertToObservable(value) : ko.observable(value);
        }
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

It has dependency to jQuery, but can be rewritten if don't use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you can't access to DueDate ?
Because in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zqnzh/2/) I can.

```
// json nested data
var data = {
    "Level1": [{
        "Level2": {
            "DueDate": "\/Date(1362124800000)\/",
        },
            "Number": 5499
    }]
};
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

var dueDate = viewModel.Level1()[0].Level2.DueDate;

alert(typeof dueDate);
```